# How do I prevent ASP.Net from sending a default charset?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, iis-7.5, content-type

I'm working on building some web pages for testing various vulnerability scenarios, but ASP.Net, or IIS, is doing too good a job of protecting me from myself.

One of the things I'm trying to do is return responses with various Content-Type headers, with and without charset declarations.  The problem I that if I leave out the charset, then ASP.Net seems to add in utf-8 by default.

In my ASPX.cs code-behind, if I have `Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")` or `Page.ContentType = "test/html"`, I would expect to see the following header returned by the page:

```
Content-Type: text/html
```

Instead I get:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

If I use `Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1")` then I get the expected header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Is there a way to stop ASP.Net (IIS?) from appending `charset=utf-8` to the header when I don't want it?

I'm using ASP.Net 4.0 and IIS 7.5.

Comment: Why do you need to remove this default `charset=utf-8`?

Comment: @murali Because I have another project which looks for this kind of thing, and I want to test its functionality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
Response.Charset = "";
```

Comment: Doh! Can't believe it was that simple. I was trying all sorts of things with setting headers, and the Page object, and didn't even realise this property was there.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Useful answer!, instead of an empty string or is there some constant value you could assign? (i.e. Charsets.UTF8, I'm not looking for String.Empty of course)